# is includePadding not recommended as PlatformTextStyle is deprecated in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm developing with jetpack compose.
When I use includePadding = false,
in compose, the feature is used like below

```
platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(includeFontPadding = false)
```

But the jetpack compose docs say like below,

```
includeFontPadding was added to Android in order to prevent clipping issues on tall scripts. 
However that issue has been fixed since Android 28. 
Jetpack Compose backports the fix for Android versions prior to Android 28. 
Therefore the original reason why includeFontPadding was needed in invalid on Compose.
This configuration was added for migration of the apps in case some code or 
design was relying includeFontPadding=true behavior and will be removed
```

As above mentioned, I'm confused with whether to use includePadding.
Is there other way to use includePadding = false or Is it not recommended to use includePadding = false?

Comment: The doc says everything . the clipping was fixed a while ago https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.2.0-alpha05 .

Comment: @ADM Nope, in 1.2.0-beta01 in is turned ON by default again.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.2.0-beta01

PlatformTextStyle, however, id marked as deprecated - and it is really confusing.

Comment: @ADM fixed what exactly? see the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75832996/jetpack-compose-platformtextstyle-includefontpadding-is-deprecated-so-what-is-t

Comment: Is confusing for me as well, I need to remove the padding included by default, my implementation has nothing to do with the coment and the deprecation coment also don't tell what should we use instead

Answer (score 0):

Based on what is relevant at the time of the answer, if you are using a version less than 1.6.0-alpha01, then you can use it without problems and not think about the deprecation signature

> Update June 2023: Compose ui 1.6.0-alpha01 is the first version with includeFontPadding switched to false by default.

> Use PlatformTextStyle API from Compose 1.2.0 to configure includeFontPadding. For few compose versions it was deprecated on purpose to indicate that it is a compatibility API, but has been undeprecated in compose 1.5 to encourage developers to use it.

or you can simply upgrade to the latest version and be happy

[read more here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b)