# Jetpack Compose PlatformTextStyle includeFontPadding is deprecated, so what is the solution?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

```
val headlineRegular: TextStyle = TextStyle(
    fontWeight = FontWeight.W400,
    fontSize = 16.sp,
    lineHeight = 22.4.sp,
    letterSpacing = 0.3.sp,
    platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
        includeFontPadding = false
    ),
),
```

[image]

with `platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(includeFontPadding = true)`:

[image]

without:

[image]

text is not centered within the container.

So what did they fix exactly?

My code:

```
TextButton(
    modifier = modifier,
    enabled = enabled,
    colors = colors,
    onClick = onClick
) {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_logout),
        contentDescription = "Logout icon",
        modifier = Modifier
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
    Text(
        text = stringResource(R.string.logout),
        style = LocalAppType.current.headlineRegular
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has since been un-deprecated and should be OK to use. Also, since compose ui 1.6.0-alpha01 "includeFontPadding" should be false by default.

> PlatformTextStyle.includeFontPadding is
> undeprecated. Our original intent was to remove the
> field, however the feedback shows that developers
> need this configuration option. Therefore removing
> deprecation from the field

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2534105

> Update June 2023: Compose ui 1.6.0-alpha01 is the first version with includeFontPadding switched to false by default.
> Use PlatformTextStyle API from Compose 1.2.0 to configure includeFontPadding. For few compose versions it was deprecated on purpose to indicate that it is a compatibility API, but has been undeprecated in compose 1.5 to encourage developers to use it.
> Test your UI using includeFontPadding set to false and make any necessary adjustments.
> Use LineHeightStyle API to match your designs easier.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b